# What does <String> in DropdownMenuItem<String> mean?

Tags: flutter, dart

In Dart, as you know, we specify types by attaching them in front of a list or a map like below.

```
List<String> listOfStrings = [ ... ];
Map<String, int> listOfInts = { ... };
```

Then I came across this weird syntax,

```
DropdownButton<String>( ... );
DropdownMenuItem<String>( ... );
```

Those are widget builders, which are classes, right? How come `<String>` can be attached there? What does that mean?

Comment: This might help - https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Often in many programming languages, there is a feature called `Generics` that aims to provide type safety and ease of supporting multiple types without needing to define method signature for every known class.

Dart is no exception and supports `Generics`. If you check the `DropdownButton` [documentation](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/DropdownButton-class.html), you can see that the method signature is defined like this.

```
DropdownButton<T> class
```

This means that any `T`ype can be supplied to DropdownButton, and it will be "passed" down to other underlying methods. Down in the documentation, you can search for use of `T`, and below are few examples.

```
...
items → List<DropdownMenuItem<T>>?
...
onChanged → ValueChanged<T?>?
```

In the above cases, `T` will automatically be whatever you initially supplied with DropdownButton<`T`>.

In your example, because you use `String` for `T`, all underlying instance variables or methods that use `T` will use `String` as well.

Generics is an important programming language concept, and you will pretty much see it everywhere so I recommend you to read the Dart lang documentation about generics.
https://dart.dev/guides/language/language-tour#generics